# How do I add HTML to a PHP function

Tags: php, html

```
add_action( 'init', 'wc_readd_add_to_cart_buttons' );
function wc_readd_add_to_cart_buttons() {
  //add to cart button loop
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
```

I am adding back a button in WooCommerceand need to have a `<br>` before the button. How do I insert a `<b>` inside the above action?

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'echo' (or 'print') to enclose HTML, but sometimes that gets a bit messy with complex HTML, not to mention having to escape quote/double-quote character.

So try something like this:

```
function myfunction() {
  // after this next, plain HTML
  ?>
  <div class='myclass'><h1 align="center">This is a heading</h1></div>
  <!-- more HTML code here -->
  <?php   // back to PHP
  // .. some more PHP stuff
return;
}
```

That allows you to put in some complex HTML (or a bunch of it) without having to use `echo/print`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are using init and then adding the function to the WC action.
The following should work:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_readd_add_to_cart_buttons', 10 );
if (!function_exists('wc_readd_add_to_cart_buttons')){
   function wc_readd_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    //add to cart button loop
    echo "<br />";
    woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();
  }
}
```